# Al hacer return me deja de funcionar el menu

Tags: javascript

Estoy teniendo un problema en el siguiente codigo:

```js
let icono_carrito = document.getElementById("icono-carrito");
let carrito = document.querySelector(".carrito");
let cerrar_carrito = document.getElementById("cerrar-carrito");

cerrar_carrito.addEventListener("click", function(){
    carrito.classList.remove('carrito-show');
    localStorage.setItem("carrito-show", "hide");
    //console.log("click en cerrar " + localStorage.getItem("carrito-show"))
});

window.onload = function(){
    if(localStorage.getItem("carrito-show")==="show"){
        carrito.classList.add('carrito-show');
    
    }else{
        alert("retorno");
        return;
    }
    }

function mostrar_carrito(){
    if(localStorage.getItem("carrito-show")==="hide"){
        carrito.classList.add('carrito-show');
        localStorage.setItem("carrito-show", "show");

    }else{
        carrito.classList.remove('carrito-show');
        localStorage.setItem("carrito-show", "hide");
    }

}


 let $botonMenu = document.querySelector("#icono_menu");
    let $icono_menu = document.querySelector("#bar_menu");
    let $containerAll = document.querySelector(".container_all");

    let $container_all_producto = document.querySelector(".container_all_producto");
   

    $botonMenu.addEventListener("click", () => {
      let $menu = document.getElementById("menu");

      //Icono de abrir menu
      if ($icono_menu.className == "fas fa-bars") {
        $menu.classList.remove("animate__animated", "animate__slideOutLeft");
        setTimeout(() => {
          $icono_menu.className = "fas fa-close";
          $icono_menu.style.color = "white";
        }, "0500");
        $icono_menu.style.zIndex = "100";
        $menu.style.display = "flex";
        $menu.classList.add(
          "animate__animated",
          "animate__slideInLeft",
          "animate__faster"
        );


        

      } else if ($icono_menu.className == "fas fa-close") {
        //Icono para cerrar menu removeProperty

        $menu.classList.remove("animate__animated", "animate__slideInLeft");
        $menu.classList.add("animate__animated", "animate__slideOutLeft");
        $icono_menu.className = "fas fa-bars";
        $icono_menu.style.color = "black";

        $menu.style.display = "none";
        if ($containerCarrousel) {
          $containerCarrousel.classList.toggle("contenedor_carrousel_position");
          $containerAll.classList.toggle("container_all_opacidad");
        }

        if ($containerAllCatalogo) {
          $containerAllCatalogo.classList.toggle(
            "container_all_catalogo_opacidad"
          );
        }
        if($container_all_producto){
          let $producto_seleccionado = document.querySelector(".producto_seleccionado");
          $container_all_producto.classList.toggle("container_all_producto_opacidad");
          $producto_seleccionado.classList.toggle("producto_seleccionado_position")
        }

      }
    });
  } else {
    $icono_menu.className = "fas fa-bars";
    $menu.style.display = "none";

  }
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #ffffff63;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: rgba(233, 230, 230, 0.521);
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }

  .container__header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0px 20px;
  }
  .icono_menu_mobile {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 20px;
    right: 10px;
    float: right;
    font-size: 30px;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  .logo {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .logo img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  .menu {
    background-color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
    margin: auto;
    width: 85vw;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    z-index: 100;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .menu > nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    margin-top: 5vh;
  }
  .menu > nav > ul > .inicio__activo {
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color_secundario);
  }

  .menu > nav > ul {
    gap: 20px;
    position: relative;

    display: flex;
    /* border: 1px solid; */
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .menu > nav > ul > li > a {
    color: var(--color_texto);
  }
  .socialMedia {
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 57px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    gap: 20px;
    align-items: center;
  }
      /*CARRITO DE COMPRA*/
      div.carrito{
        position: absolute;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         background-color: #ececec;
         right: -200vw;
         z-index: 100;
         bottom: 0;
         transition: all 1s ease;
       }
       div.carrito-show{
         right: 0;
       }
     #cerrar-carrito{
         position: absolute;
         right: 10px;
         top: 10px;
         font-size: 2rem;
         color: var(--color_texto);     
       }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Catalogo - Rescate</title>

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/775c1cb76a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<header>
        <div class="container__header">
            
            <div class="icono_menu_mobile" id="icono_menu">
                <i id="bar_menu" class="fas fa-bars" ></i>
            </div>
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="img/logo-removebg-preview.png" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="menu" id="menu">
                <nav id="nav_menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
                        <li class="inicio__activo"><a href="">Catalogo</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Adopcion</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contactos</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>


            </div>
            <div class="socialMedia">
                <a href="#">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M416 208c0 45.9-14.9 88.3-40 122.7L502.6 457.4c12.5 12.5 12.5 32.8 0 45.3s-32.8 12.5-45.3 0L330.7 376c-34.4 25.2-76.8 40-122.7 40C93.1 416 0 322.9 0 208S93.1 0 208 0S416 93.1 416 208zM208 352a144 144 0 1 0 0-288 144 144 0 1 0 0 288z"/></svg>                    </a>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path d="M304 128a80 80 0 1 0 -160 0 80 80 0 1 0 160 0zM96 128a128 128 0 1 1 256 0A128 128 0 1 1 96 128zM49.3 464H398.7c-8.9-63.3-63.3-112-129-112H178.3c-65.7 0-120.1 48.7-129 112zM0 482.3C0 383.8 79.8 304 178.3 304h91.4C368.2 304 448 383.8 448 482.3c0 16.4-13.3 29.7-29.7 29.7H29.7C13.3 512 0 498.7 0 482.3z"/></svg>
                </a>
                    <a href="#" onclick="mostrar_carrito()">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="icono-carrito" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 448 512" ><path d="M160 112c0-35.3 28.7-64 64-64s64 28.7 64 64v48H160V112zm-48 48H48c-26.5 0-48 21.5-48 48V416c0 53 43 96 96 96H352c53 0 96-43 96-96V208c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48H336V112C336 50.1 285.9 0 224 0S112 50.1 112 112v48zm24 48a24 24 0 1 1 0 48 24 24 0 1 1 0-48zm152 24a24 24 0 1 1 48 0 24 24 0 1 1 -48 0z"/></svg>
                </a>

            </div>
                <div class="carrito">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark" id="cerrar-carrito"></i>                
                </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Estoy creando un e-commerce y ahorita estoy creando el carrito mediate localStorage, y inserte un windows.onload para que cada vez que se inicie la pagina este viendo si en el localstorage existe la clase "carrito-show" que si existe cada vez que entre a la pagina lo primero que vea sea su carrito abierto, pero estoy teniendo problemas en ello, ya que al darle clic al "carrito" funciona el codigo, pero deja de funcionar el menu en todo momento, queda inhabilitado y no se el por que, alguien que me pueda ayudar en ese sentido, utilizo el else{return;} porque me ayudaron en esta pagina de esta manera que si no existe tal elemento haga return para volver a entrar en el if que se activara al hacer clic en "carrito" para que se pueda mostrar el mismo. **Ver en modo movil **

Aclaro! ninguna de las variables tienen el mismo nombre para que deje de funcionar

Comment: "Y es que cada vez con el window.onload se vive haciendo return del else, ya que no tiene la clase, y eso me afecta en el menu" no se entiende mucho pero... de qué forma te afecta el que no tenga la class `carrito-show`. Podrías agregar el HTML para que quede más claro tu problema

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, hablas de un menú el cual no aparece en el código, entonces como podríamos saber como te afecta ??

Comment: ¿Por qué hacés el `else return`?

Comment: Para que se vuelva a ejecutar

Comment: El ultimo else que tienes no debería estar ahi justo después de un punto y coma, debería tirarte error de sintaxis si tu editor de texto no es el bloc de notas. El alert('retorno') no es necesario...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elimina el ultimo else del código que expusiste aquí, también el alert y el return dentro del else en `window.onload`, return no hace que algo se *'vuelva a ejecutar'* sino que sale de la función donde se encuentra, puede ser con algún valor o sin ningún valor. En su lugar usa el else para setear 'carrito-show' como 'hide' en el localStorage en caso de que al cargar la pagina dicho dato no se encuentre ahi:

```
window.onload = function () {
  if (localStorage.getItem("carrito-show") === "show") {
    carrito.classList.add("carrito-show");
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("carrito-show", "hide");
  }
};
```

Y en `mostrarCarrito` no necesitas hacer ninguna comprobación, puedes hacerlo sencillamente así (como hiciste con la función en onClick):

```
function mostrar_carrito() {
  carrito.classList.add("carrito-show");
  localStorage.setItem("carrito-show", "show");
}
```

Esos son los únicos cambios que hice.